# SQL Query returns null?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to get all names of my products and push them into an array. If I use the SQL Query (`SELECT name FROM wp_all_import_xml GROUP BY name`) in phpmyadmin I get this:
[image]

But if I use the query in my script I get this array:

```
    array (
  0 => NULL,
  1 => NULL,
  2 => NULL,
  3 => NULL,
  4 => NULL,
  ...)
```

So, the query must return null. But why? - Everything is correct!
I do not get any connection error or query error... Where is my error?

I already tried to decode the strings and I also tried `$myTitles[] = $tmp`. But it also doesn't work... Any ideas?

And because everything in the `$myTitles` array is `null`, the script always enters the `if(!(in_array($title, $myTitles)` condition and I cannot execute what I actual want... I can only execute this, if the array and the condition is really true!

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    // Set up WordPress environment 
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
}

unlink('deleteOldProducts.txt');

$myfile = fopen('deleteOldProducts.txt', "w");
$database_gk = new mysqli("localhost", "censored", "censored", "censored");
$database_jt = new mysqli("localhost", "censored", "censored", "censored");
$myTitles = array();
$string = "";

if($database_jt->connect_errno){
    $string .= "+++Couldn't connect to database_jt!+++\n\n");
}

if($database_gk->connect_errno){
    $string .= "+++Couldn't connect to database_gk!+++\n\n");
}

$values_jt = $database_jt->query("SELECT name FROM `wp_all_import_xml` GROUP BY name");
$string .= $database_jt->error . "\n";


while($rowj = $values_jt->fetch_assoc()){
    $tmp = utf8_encode($row["name"]);
    array_push($myTitles, $tmp);
    $tmp = null;
}

$values_gk = $database_gk->query("SELECT `post_title` FROM `fWR6qIN_posts` where post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY `post_title`");
$string .= $database_gk->error . "\n";

$string .= "+++ Start of Check +++\n\nMein Array:\n" . var_export($myTitles, true) . "\n\n";
$i = 1;

while($row = $values_gk->fetch_assoc()){
    $title = utf8_decode($row["post_title"]);

    if(!(in_array($title, $myTitles))){
        $string .= $i . ":\t" . $title . "\n";
        $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $title = null;
}

$string .= "\n +++ End of Check! +++";
fwrite($myfile, $string);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: Don't make multiple database connections. You can reuse the same one for different queries. (Unless they're actually different databases, hard to tell from your edit...)

Comment: why are you grouping by name if you are only fetching names?

Comment: GROUP BY doesn't make much sense there. If you want to exclude duplicates use UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` isn't correct. On `while` you are using `$rowj` but on `array_push` you are using `$row`. You can try the following code instead:

```
while($row = $values_jt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myTitles[] = utf8_encode($row["name"]);
}
```

> **Note:** If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Thank You! - But I have one question left. With utf8_encode, the chars are correct. But if I use utf8_encode also for the other SQL Query, the chars aren't correct... How can that happen? - The other SQL database is `utf8_general_ci` format

Comment: many possbilities. see this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I checked it already but I have no idea how to correct it... :/